# Pass value of child component to parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok, working on my second ever React app.  In this project, I am trying to use nested components (my last one just had 1 component). I've got a Button component that I am trying to render within the main App component, which is a calculator (Here is my design I am replicating in node/react locally: https://codepen.io/ryanmdoyle/pen/QBvjdw)

So far in my code, the only button I am actually implementing so far is the AC button. Everything else is copy/paste from my codepen design.  I know some aspects like the CSS classes and values are getting passed around correctly because it displays the CSS properly, but I am trying to take the value of the Button component and use that within methods in the App component. Particularly in the handleInput method. I know with an input field you can get the event.target.value but that's obviously not working!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import './App.css';

const Button = (props) => <button id={props.id} className={props.class} value={props.value} onClick={this.handleInput}>{props.value}</button>

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      resultDisplay: "",
      entryDisplay: "",
    }
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      entryDisplay: this.state.entryDisplay + event.target.value
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="grid-container">
        <div className="display">display</div>

        <Button id="clear" class={`button button-secondary`} value="ac" />

        <div id="plus-min" className="button button-secondary">+/-</div>
        <div id="percent" className="button button-secondary">%</div>

        <Button id="one" class="button button-primary" value={1} />

        <div id="two" className="button button-primary">2</div>
        <div id="three" className="button button-primary">3</div>
        <div id="four" className="button button-primary">4</div>
        <div id="five" className="button button-primary">5</div>
        <div id="six" className="button button-primary">6</div>
        <div id="seven" className="button button-primary">7</div>
        <div id="eight" className="button button-primary">8</div>
        <div id="nine" className="button button-primary">9</div>
        <div id="zero" className="button-primary">0</div>
        <div id="divide" className="button button-operator">/</div>
        <div id="multiply" className="button button-operator">*</div>
        <div id="subtract" className="button button-operator">-</div>
        <div id="add" className="button button-operator">+</div>
        <div id="decimal" className="button button-primary">.</div>
        <div id="equals" className="button button-operator">=</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Button = (props) => <button id={props.id} className={props.class} value={props.value} onClick={this.handleInput}>{props.value}</button>
```

You are trying to add a function that is not local to `Button`.

For using it you need to pass the function like this

```
<Button id="clear" class={`button button-secondary`} value="ac" click={this.handleInput}/>
```

And when you try to use the function in `Button` use it like this

```
const Button = (props) => <button id={props.id} className={props.class} value={props.value} onClick={() => props.click()}>{props.value}</button>
```

One thing to remember `this` is `null` in a arrow function by default.

You must know that when ever you are trying to create a component where stateless or stateful doesnot matter its function set, variable must be separate. You cannot use it like you have tried in this case.
class in React is just like classes in other programming language almost.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, especially including the callbacks as the argument for onClick.  It took me a bit to realize I needed to do that, rather than just pass in the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in your Button component:

```
const Button = (props) => <button id={props.id} className={props.class} value={props.value} onClick={this.handleInput}>{props.value}</button>
```

**this.handleInput** isn't defined. It is defined in your App component but not in Button. If you try clicking the Button, you will get an error in the console.

What you're looking to do is pass a callback to your Button component from the App component via props:

In App:

```
<Button handleInput={this.handleInput} />
```

In Button:

```
<button onClick={props.handleInput}
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense. I now have in my App render:

`<Button id="one" class="button button-primary" value={1} handleClick={this.handleInput(1)}/>`

The component is:

`const Button = (props) => <button id={props.id} className={props.class} value={props.value} onClick={props.handleClick}>{props.value}</button>`

I changed my handleClick method in the App component to just console.log out the "value".  I want it to do that onClick, but it's just logging on the render.  So, the console on render just shows "1".  Why is the method running without clicking the button? @LMuvey @Gurpreet-Singh

Comment: @Ryan because when you pass this.handleInput(1) as props, you are actually invoking that function and passing its return value as prop! What you need to do is replace this.handleInput(1) by a callback like so: () => this.handleInput(1), which will pass a function as prop

Answer (score 1):

Replace these line in your code

**Button Component**

```
    const Button = (props) => <button id={props.id} className={props.class} value={props.value} onClick={props.onClick}>{props.value}</button>
```

**Pass props in all button Component like this**

```
<Button id="clear" class='button button-secondary' value="ac" onClick={this.handleInput}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can pass entire functions as props to your components, which is the beauty of JavaScript and React! So, essentially, write the function to clear your screen in your main App component, and then pass a reference down to your button component. Attach the function to the onClick event for your button component.

```
// App.js

...

clearScreen() => this.setState({ resultDisplay: '', entryDisplay: ''})

...


<Button id="clear" class={`button button-secondary`} value="ac" onClick={clearScreen.bind(this)} />


// ButtonComponent.js

...

<button onClick={this.props.onClick} />

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass a function as a prop down to your child component, which will then allow you to alter the parent's functionality.

For example:

```
passFunction(value) {
   // Modify passed parameter (value) from child and implement in parent
   this.setState({value: value});

   // or call that method that you want to call.
   handleInput(value);
}
<Button passFunction={this.passFunction} ... />
```

Then in Button.js or wherever the child component is:

```
this.prop.passfunction(someValueToParent)
```